# How to fix text data format fetched from backend server?

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch

My React Native (0.62.3) app `fetch` a text data from nodejs 12.x backend server. Here is the `abi` appeared on backend server:

```
 abi: [
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "_value",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "_itemName",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
...
]
```

The text is returned on backend nodejs server with:

```
return res.status(200).send({dude:_dude.deploy_address, fex:_fex.deploy_address, forsale:{abi:_forsale.abi, bytecode:_forsale.bytecode}});
```

Here is the RN code to fetch and parse the data received:

```
  let res = await fetch(beUrl, {method: "GET"});
  let res1 = await res.json();
```

The data format on console output from `res1` is quite massed up with `abi` which is a long text of array:

```
abi: '[\n\t{\n\t\t"inputs": [\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t"internalType": "uint256",\n\t\t\t\t"name": "_value",\n\t\t\t\t"type": "uint256"\....]'
```

Tried `encodeURI(abi)` but it didn't help. How to fix the format on RN of the data fetched?

Comment: try resolving it as await res.text()

Comment: res.text() throws error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the format was reserved and restored:

On nodejs/express server, `JSON.stringift` the whole return object:

```
 let obj = JSON.stringify({dude:_dude.deploy_address, fex:_fex.deploy_address, forsale:{abi:(_forsale.abi), bytecode:(_forsale.bytecode)}});
    return res.status(200).send(obj);
```

On front end, `JSON.parse` the `abi` and `bytecode`:

```
let res = await fetch(beUrl, {method: "GET", headers: {
                                                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
                                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
                                              }});
      let res1 = await res.json();
      let res3 = JSON.parse(res1.forsale.abi);
      let res4 = JSON.parse(res1.forsale.bytecode);
```

`res3` and `res4` have the text format restored to its original as it is on the nodejs/express server.